# Pine script code is giving error for Statrgy.Entry function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

As per my code below are buy and sell signals

```
buySignal = low < lower[1] and close > lower and close > open or close > upper and ta.crossover(rsiValue,rsiOverbought) and close > open 
sellSignal =  high > upper[1] and close < upper  and close < open or close < lower and ta.crossunder(rsiValue,rsiOversold) and close <open
```

It is plotted on chart correctly also

But when try to enter below

```
strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, stop=buySignal,limit=buySignal + 15 * syminfo.mintick,  oca_name="entries", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
```

It gives error saying that

> Cannot call 'operator +' with argument 'expr0'='buySignal'. An
> argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is
> expected.

Logic is that it enter Long if buySignal conditions are met then it should trigger stop limit  order with current candle high + 15 (Buffer points) and stop loss = previous candle low - 15 (Buffer Points)

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

The current candle high is 'high'.
The previous candle low is 'low[1].

Change ;

```
strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, stop=buySignal,limit=buySignal + 15 * syminfo.mintick,  oca_name="entries", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
```

To :

```
strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, stop=low[1] - 15* syminfo.mintick, limit=high + 15 * syminfo.mintick,  oca_name="entries", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
```